# LISTAGG Func Performance in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Running below SQL in Snowflake,

```
select I_CLASS_ID,LISTAGG(I_CLASS,',') OVER(PARTITION BY I_CLASS_ID) 
FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."ITEM" 
WHERE I_CLASS_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Running the SQL using a XSmall Warehouse.

The query took over 40 mins of time and still was running and had to abort. This table is considerably small so trying to understand why it is taking this long time. The profile states that 1 out of 4 nodes doing most of the work. Any reason why?

```
select LISTAGG(I_CLASS,',') OVER(PARTITION BY I_CLASS_ID) 
FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."ITEM" 
WHERE I_CLASS_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Above one is running in an instant through.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, does the aggregation for every row, so if you have 1 million rows, you will get 1 million rows, with all the ids.

Where-as the second while should give the same results, the opitmizer might be able to tell it can run the SQL this:

```
SELECT A.I_CLASS_ID
    B.LIST
FROM FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."ITEM" AS A
JOIN (
    SELECT I_CLASS_ID, 
        LISTAGG(I_CLASS,',') AS list
    FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."ITEM" 
    WHERE I_CLASS_ID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 1
) AS B
    ON A.I_CLASS_ID = B.I_CLASS_ID;
```

which will return 1 million rows, but will be super fast.

Where what I suspect you actually wanted was just the inner part.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the query plan was for #2, but I doubt it ran in an "instant".
It tried both your queries and killed them after 2+ minutes.
I then ran:
select I_CLASS_ID,LISTAGG(I_CLASS,',') OVER(PARTITION BY I_CLASS_ID)
FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."ITEM"
WHERE I_CLASS_ID IS  NULL;
which ran under 1 sec.

I then ran:

```
select i_class_id,avg(length(i_class)),max(length(i_class)) from item group by 1;
```

Followed by:

```
select i_class_id,count(i_class)*8 from item where i_class_id is not null group by 1;
```

You are creating very large listaggs, ranging in size from 125 KB to 625 KB.
Suggest you try larger DW size. Also, be sure that your long running query wasn't due to queueing.